# Adding items to a dictionary using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a problem with recursion I'm studying,

If I try to create a recursive function to add items to a list all is ok.
Example:

```
def recursion(n):
if n == 0:
    list=["lelvel 0"]
    return [0] + list
else:
    list=["level"+str(n)]
    return [n] +list + recursion(n-1)
```

If I want to create a recursive function to add items in a dictionary gives me several errors.
I need for example, to create a dictionary with dict = {lion:0, rat:1}
i have tried this code but not work:

```
def recursion(n):
if n == 0:
    return {"lion": 0}
else:
    return {"rat":1} + recursion(n-1)
```

with this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'dict'
I also tried this code:

```
def recursion(n):
if n == 0:
    dict = {"lion": 0}
    return dict
else:
    dict = {"rat": 1}
    return dict.update(recursion(n-1))
```

But return is None.

my question is how do I get me back to the dictionary with lion {0, rat: 1} without using more features and without using a dictionary global?

Comment: ok i have edit all question tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator for two lists to concatenate them.

```
def prova(n):
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    else:
        return [n] + prova(n-1)

>>> prova(3)
[3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'd like to understand why my code did not work. The basic idea was that right? where wrong?
sorry for my english i use google translator

Comment: @Nurael: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27105968/3821804), maybe it'll help you understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to understand why my code did not work.

I simplifyed your code to help you understand it:

```
def prova(n): 
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return [prova(n-1)]
```

Comment: tnx. I have understand. Now i have edit my first post, can you help me with it? tnx